# Export to PDF - Multiple pages

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services, export-to-pdf

I created one report with various subreports. i set up the following properties page size and interactive size in report, and page size in body, all to A4 size.
When I export to pdf, it creates multiple pages for each page in the report presented, cutting tables and puts in another page The font size is huge compared to what I see in the report.

Anyone have suggestions to solve this problem? It seems to be problem sizes, but once you have everything set up to A4, I do not see what can be more.

Comment: does the main report include sub reports in it ? with tables ?

Comment: There's a reason why you got the message about poor quality of your question title: "problem" isn't very descriptive (and neither is "probem"). Please don't "fix" that by cheating the system, but provide a meaningful question title. (If you can't think of a good title you may need to have a peek at [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)).

Comment: @GilPeretz yes i have subreports inside tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you problem is a normal behavior of ssrs, let me explain:

If you have a main report with lets say 1 sub report in it. and your subreport is a table then your table rows are causing this issue:
While in the main report the sub-report may look like as small rectangle. the actual subreport is containing a table which can grow according the amount of data.
[image]

the solution is simple:

- if you know the max records of the table, and you manage to fit the size of the subreport - you are good.
- additional option is to define the `canGrow` property of the subreport (in the main report)